# Como separar acesso HTTP e IMAP de um mesmo domínio em servidores distintos?

Tags: http, dns, amazon-aws, imap

Tenho conta de hospedagem na Locaweb, logicamente **IMAP e HTTP**. Estou pretendendo migrar para a AWS *(Amazon Web Service)*. Porém, antes de fazer tal mudança, pretendo primeiro mudar apenas o acesso ao site (HTTP) do domínio, e deixar as contas de e-mail IMAP ainda na Locaweb (mesmo domínio). Os emails possuem 10GB, e preciso fazer isso com calma.

Uma forma fácil de fazer este "*redirecionamento*"? Pensei em mexer nas configurações de **DNS** dentro da Locaweb e redirecionar o acesso ao site para o IP no AWS. Mas não sei se isso vai afetar o e-mail.

Comment: Olá, você conseguiu resolver o dilema? Estou nesse mesmo barco...

Comment: @WilliamBertan Sim, consegui. Foi mal, esqueci de colocar aqui a solução. Me dê alguns minutos para posta aqui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi a questão da seguinte forma. A única etapa que realmente é diferente é a configuração na Locaweb. As configurações na AWS ocorrem normalmente como se estivesse criando um novo domínio.

**Ações na Locaweb**

- Entrei no Gerenciador de DNS
- Alterei a **Entrada** "**.**" (*ponto mesmo*), do tipo "**A**", para o **IP público da minha instância na AWS** *(isso quer dizer que da pasta raiz pra frente está redirecionado para o IP)*
- A configuração de domínio continua normal na Locaweb

**Ações na AWS**

- Acessei o recurso **Route 53** e inseri uma nova "**Hosted Zone**" do meu domínio *(antes da Locaweb)* com todas as configurações básicas e normais de se associar uma Hosted Zone com uma instância *(aqui vai o mesmo IP de minha instância na AWS que configurei acima na Locaweb)*
- Faço a configuração normal no Apache para receber o domínio e pasta raiz.

Dessa forma, sempre que eu acesso HTTP (com ou sem WWW) é redirecionado para a AWS. Se eu acessar meu e-mail pelo Outlook por exemplo, funciona normalmente. Assim como o Webmail.